# Angular 2 - Directives declared yet still have errors

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In `RootModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ModuleA
    ],
    declarations: [
        ScrollToWhen
    ],
    bootstrap: [BootComponent],
})
class RootModule {}
```

In one of the component template inside Module A, I use `ScrollToWhen`, but I got error: `Can't bind to 'scrollToWhen' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`.

Why?

[image]

`Error: Unexpected directive 'HbClass' imported by the module 'Module'`

Comment: we need more information, how do u use the directive, what does the code of the directive look like, ...

Comment: It would be better to past the code instead of a screenshot. Are `HbClass`, `Default`, `Asset`, `Photon` modules? You have them in `declarations` in `RootModule` and `imports` in `Module`. `imports` is for modules, `declarations` for directives, components, and pipes.

Comment: So I should create a `MyAppCommonModule` and declare all commonly used directives and pipes in it then imports to modules whenever I need?

Comment: That's the way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either add `ScrollToWhen` to declarations of `ModuleA` or move it to a module that you can then add to `imports: [...]` of `ModuleA` to make it available there.

A component/directive can only be listed in **one single** module in `declarations: [...]`. Then import this module everywhere where you want to use this component/directive.

For module used for declaring directives and pipe, you need to set them in `exports` like:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        myDirectives
    ],
    exports: [
        myDirectives
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the config I missed to add. Yet after adding `import` config in Module A, I got: `Error: Unexpected directive 'MyDirective' imported by the module 'Module'`

Comment: What `import` did you add where? Can you please update your question to show what you have now?

Comment: I have embedded a screenshot

Comment: `imports: []` must not contain directives, only modules. As the error message says, it is not a module. Directives should go into `declarations: [...]` of exactly one module and then add this module to `imports: []` of the modules where you want to use it.